# Client-server applications and certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate

If in order to obtain a certificate from a trusted authority you need a valid URL address, then how do client-server applications (that are just 2 applications running onto different machines) can establish an SSL communication?

Comment: For some reason I feel like this is a question that should be asked at [http://security.stackexchange.com/](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

SSL doesn't specifically require you to have a certificate with a validated URL, it just requires the server to present a certificate (except anonymous ciphers). This certificate could be a self-signed certificate which the client could accept as part of the handshake or a self-generated chain of certs with a private CA common to both the client and server. Even on a browser, if you connect to a website which presents a certificate which has a different common name than the URL domain name, you get a warning which you can ignore and proceed to the website.

Comment: so for such an application we can request certificates from a CA (for e.g. verisign) without a domain name?

Comment: No, you can generate your own certificate (self-signed) and use it. You can try this command `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days XXX`

Comment: I do have my own and I am using it. But that is just the case for my personal app. I am wondering what happens to distribution apps. Do they self sign them?

Comment: Yes, you can use self-signed certs even in distribution apps.